# CentOS 6.3 (kernel 2.6.32-279) & wl-kmod won't compile

Tags: centos, compiling, broadcom

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to compile a Broadcom driver for use on my CentOS laptop. Previously, I had used the instructions located [here](http://elrepo.org/tiki/wl-kmod&highlight=broadcom) to compile and it worked flawlessly.

Now, I cannot get the driver to compile. Admittedly the errors look like something I should be able to simply fix, however, I have not found a way to get it to work for me yet. Here is what I get when I run the rpmbuild on my laptop:

```
$rpmbuild --rebuild --target=`uname -m` wl-kmod-5_100_82_112-3.el6.elrepo.nosrc.rpm 
Installing wl-kmod-5_100_82_112-3.el6.elrepo.nosrc.rpm
warning: InstallSourcePackage at: psm.c:244: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID baadae52: NOKEY
warning: user ajb does not exist - using root
warning: group ajb does not exist - using root
warning: user ajb does not exist - using root
warning: group ajb does not exist - using root
warning: user ajb does not exist - using root
warning: group ajb does not exist - using root
Building target platforms: i686
Building for target i686
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.BX2aRY
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf wl-kmod-5_100_82_112
+ /bin/mkdir -p wl-kmod-5_100_82_112
+ cd wl-kmod-5_100_82_112
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ cd /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd wl-kmod-5_100_82_112
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/jblair/rpmbuild/SOURCES/hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ /bin/sed -i 's/\/lib\/modules\/`uname -r`\/build/\"\${KSRC}\"/' Makefile
+ echo 'override wl * weak-updates/wl'
+ /bin/cat
+ /bin/cat
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.T8r6eV
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd wl-kmod-5_100_82_112
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
++ uname -r
+ /usr/bin/make KSRC=/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.i686
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C "/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.i686" M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.i686'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  LD      /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.o
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:64: warning: 'enum tx_power_setting' declared inside parameter list
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:64: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1110: warning: 'enum tx_power_setting' declared inside parameter list
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1110: error: parameter 2 ('type') has incomplete type
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: In function 'wl_cfg80211_set_tx_power':
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1123: error: 'TX_POWER_AUTOMATIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1123: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1123: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1125: error: 'TX_POWER_LIMITED' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1131: error: 'TX_POWER_FIXED' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: At top level:
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1649: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1651: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1652: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1653: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1654: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1658: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: In function 'wl_inform_single_bss':
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1817: error: too few arguments to function 'ieee80211_channel_to_frequency'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: In function 'wl_bss_roaming_done':
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2117: warning: passing argument 2 of 'cfg80211_roamed' from incompatible pointer type
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'struct ieee80211_channel *' but argument is of type 'u8 *'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2117: warning: passing argument 4 of 'cfg80211_roamed' makes pointer from integer without a cast
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'const u8 *' but argument is of type 's32'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2117: warning: passing argument 5 of 'cfg80211_roamed' makes integer from pointer without a cast
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'size_t' but argument is of type 'u8 *'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2117: warning: passing argument 6 of 'cfg80211_roamed' makes pointer from integer without a cast
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'const u8 *' but argument is of type 's32'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2117: error: too few arguments to function 'cfg80211_roamed'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: In function 'wl_bss_connect_done':
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2149: warning: passing argument 2 of 'cfg80211_roamed' from incompatible pointer type
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'struct ieee80211_channel *' but argument is of type 'u8 *'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2149: warning: passing argument 4 of 'cfg80211_roamed' makes pointer from integer without a cast
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'const u8 *' but argument is of type 's32'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2149: warning: passing argument 5 of 'cfg80211_roamed' makes integer from pointer without a cast
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'size_t' but argument is of type 'u8 *'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2149: warning: passing argument 6 of 'cfg80211_roamed' makes pointer from integer without a cast
include/net/cfg80211.h:3035: note: expected 'const u8 *' but argument is of type 's32'
/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:2149: error: too few arguments to function 'cfg80211_roamed'
make[2]: *** [/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jblair/rpmbuild/BUILD/wl-kmod-5_100_82_112] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.i686'
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.T8r6eV (%build)


RPM build errors:
    InstallSourcePackage at: psm.c:244: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID baadae52: NOKEY
    user ajb does not exist - using root
    group ajb does not exist - using root
    user ajb does not exist - using root
    group ajb does not exist - using root
    user ajb does not exist - using root
    group ajb does not exist - using root
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.T8r6eV (%build)
```

Any help you can provide would be most appreciated. I will not have access to the box in question until this evening, but I should be able to answer most questions and will try any suggestions I receive as soon as I return from work tonight.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted, it looks like there's a problem linking the **wl_cfg80211.o** file, possibly a library missing.  Some of the other errors seem to imply you're missing a header/include file to define things to match the library.

Comment: Ah, well, that does not sound in my area of expertise. I was hoping that there would be something that would be mentioned and I can go, "Duh, I should have known that," and fixed it. Thanks for the info about the header/include file!

Comment: You might try finding the source code in a more conventional format, allowing the './configure; make; make install' compilation sequence.  If nothing else, you'll at least get better error messages if something *IS* missing.